# Can't enable iCloud Desktop Documents Sync in Sierra

Tags: data-synchronization, desktop, macos, icloud

Every time I try to enable iCloud Desktop and Documents Sync it spins the spinner for a while and it looks like the setting is enabled, but as soon as I reopen settings it is deselected.

Console produces errors like these:

```
bird [ERROR] can't open Documents or Desktop <private>; error 2 (<private>)
bird [ERROR] Failed to apply sync policy: -1 for folder type: 2, error: <private>
accountsd [ERROR] iCloud Desktop Settings change failed: <private>, resetting to old value
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be something wrong with your account? Maybe your iCloud account is causing the issue.

Comment: Everythin else seem to be working. I have payed and enough free space in the cloud.

Comment: I had the same issue but the 10.12.1 update (today) fixed it.

Comment: I am getting this on a brand new Mac starting with 10.14.2. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ElliotChance Flipping the switch back and forth finally enabled it.

Comment: @firedev How many times flipping back and forth? I'm still stuck with the exact same symptoms: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362564/what-could-cause-icloud-drive-to-refuse-to-sync-desktop-documents

Comment: @JacobFord Actually once or twice if I am not mistaken.