# icloud drive > "desktop and documents folder" will not stay checked/ticked after MacOS Catalina Beta 10.5?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, finder, data-synchronization

icloud drive > "desktop and documents folder" will not stay checked/ticked after MacOS Catalina Beta 10.5. How to resolve?

- Files are not syncing between devices,
- Going to icloud.com you can upload and syncs automatically.
- Apps are not syncing if they use icloud (eg. Goodnotes, Ulysses)
- Ulysses creates a space, but only says downloading, without completion
- Finder on MacOS shows "document - local" folder empty
- Trying to disable icloud can't be done, tries to create a recover or local folder that does not complete and boxes for other services won't stay unchecked/unticked.

Comment: Hey @jmcleodrx do you still experience this?? I've been dealing with this today on Catalina (10.15.1) and it's driving me insane! I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: @MarcFletcher [What could cause iCloud Drive to refuse to sync Desktop & Documents?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362564/what-could-cause-icloud-drive-to-refuse-to-sync-desktop-documents?rq=1)